# how to install noUiSlider?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to install this slider (https://refreshless.com/nouislider/)

I've downloaded the nouislider.js & nouislider.css files and put them in separate folders (css & js) and created an html file and a div with the name of the slider.

Then added the .js link in the body, and the .css link in the head. what am I missing? I know this might be a silly question but I have no idea how to create the slider or what to try next...

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nouislider.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="slider"></div>

  <script src="js/nouislider.js"></script>

  <script>
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
      start: [20, 80],
      connect: true,
      range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
      }
    });

  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I tested your code on my pc and it works fine. The slider appears. What is the problem? And what do you want to do next?

Comment: It seems if this is not working then you relative paths might be wrong and not linking to the correct file.

Comment: Is it possible to show us the console error?

Comment: I just tested it on jsfiddle by pasting the whole css/js and added this html and it still doesn't show up.

Comment: @Thanasis can you post a jsfiddle with it working please?

Comment: @Enjayy paths are good, just tripple checked.

Comment: @NipBoss Well it also works on jsfiddle. Seems I cant save it because it's too big. But you have to put the script from your code  under the nouislider javascript. Something like this: [https://jsfiddle.net/3bbn7tnn/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/3bbn7tnn/2/)

Comment: @Thanasis just inserted the code in the js file and ran it and the slider showed up, thanks!